# Tensorflow feed_dict doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow, feed

I have the following error:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'i' with dtype float and
>   shape [2,1]

When running the below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
i = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2, 1], name="i")
t = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2, 1], name="t")
wih = tf.Variable([[0.1, 0.12],[0.2, 0.17]], name="wih")
wbh = tf.Variable([[0.8],[0.25]], name="wbh")
h = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(wih, i) + wbh)
who = tf.Variable([[0.05, 0.33],[0.4, 0.07]], name="who")
wbo = tf.Variable([[0.15],[0.7]], name="wbo")
o = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(who, h) + wbo) 
e = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(t, o)
ts = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(e)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for iterations in range(10000):
        sess.run(ts, feed_dict={i:[[0.15],[0.35]], t:[[0.0],[1.0]]})
```

Why is `feed_dict` not working?

Comment: I just ran the code you posted and it works for me. (python 3.5.2, tensorflow 1.14.0)

Comment: Please mention the Tensorflow and Python version. Your code works for me as well with Python version 2.7.15 and Tensorflow version 1.11.0

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for "my mistake". The code as given above works also for me. Originally I had in the session-part also some print commands to show the state of the net - i.e. print(sess.run(h)) - and I forgot to include a feed_dict-part in these commands   - i.e. print(sess.run(h, feed_dict={i:[[0.15],[0.35]]}). This was the reason, why I got this error message, but it was hard for me to assign the error message to these commands, because the given line numbers were not very helpfull. Sorry!